# Do html friendly email clients generally support CSS stylesheets?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

Or should I just use inline styling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No do not use stylesheets.  Use inline styles.

See this for some information http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/

This explains what CSS is supported or not http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Here is a Template to get you started http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

Comment: Here are some more templates, courtesy of Mail Chimp https://github.com/mailchimp/Email-Blueprints

Answer (score 0):

Some do some don't. Generally I found it's better to just use inline styling for it as the email apps will ask you to download them separately.

Also test a lot with them cos the CSS support in outlook (for example) is dodgy at best.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good guide on what is supported by who http://campaignmonitor.com/css/

Keep in mind that now, the iPhone email client counts as one more that has a fair CSS support, so if your customers happen to be iPhone users, you might be in luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely use inline styling. I was treating emails as pretty much HTML documents for a while and learned the hard way that some of my users were receiving blank emails.

A good email client will support external CSS, but if you need to be sure that the recipients will be able to read the email no matter how crappy thier client, then use inline styles.